# Sonar runner not able to run cppcheck

Tags: c, sonarqube

I have a c project and a c plugin of sonar. Sonar was not able to run the cppcheck automatically and give the results.
Is there a way that sonar can run the cppcheck which is installed locallay ?
Always i see in the sonar log
12:56:15.608 INFO  - Sensor Cppcheck...
after this it complains cppcheckreport is not available and giving error.

Comment: Please post your code, please post the error message.  Please post 'what is 'Sonar' in the context you are using it.  Please post 'what is Cppcheck' in the context you are using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The log error indicates that the analysis can't find your pre-generated CPPCheck report. I.e. the SonarQube analysis doesn't *run* CPPCheck, it simply imports the results.

[See the docs](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/CppCheck+Reports+Import) for details on importing a CPPCheck report.